# Reading hour with scanf() - how to disregard part of input

Tags: c++

I have following data :
`10:15:14 D`
`00:15:14 T`
`00:15:14 G`

and seven variables :

`int h1,h2,m1,m2,s1,s2;`
`char mark;`

output for first line of data should be :
`h1==1`
`h2==0`
`m1==1`
`m2==5`
`s1==1`
`s2==4`
`mark=='D'`

how to disregard `":"` while using `scanf()` ?

Comment: Don't use `scanf` use an `istream`.

Comment: Please show some source code. Also scanf is not that C++.

Comment: @Aki Suihkonen `cstdio`

Comment: Why would you want the digits in separate variables? Wouldn't it be okay to have a single `hour` variable that e.g. contains the value `10`?

Comment: @Qbik Most of the `c*` libraries are obsolete.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it like

```
int h1,h2,m1,m2,s1,s2;
h1 = h2 = m1 = m2 = s1 = s2 = 0;
char mark;
if (scanf("%1d%1d:%1d%1d:%1d%1d %c", &h1, &h2, &m1, &m2, &s1, &s2, &mark) != 7)
{
    //some error handling
}
```

It's indeed strange to use different variables for digits rather than for hours, mins and seconds, like

```
scanf("%d:%d:%d %c", &h, &m, &s, &mark);
```

For those commenting that cstdio is obsolete, personally I like it more than `iostream`.

Answer (score 1):

Reading the [docs](http://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf) you'll see that it's as simple as

```
int h, m, s;
char mark;
const char* buf = "00:15:14 D";
sscanf(buf, "%d:%d:%d %c", &h, &m, &s, &mark);
fprintf(stdout, "h = %d, m = %d, s = %d, mark = %c\n", h, m, s, mark);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a trash variable to scan the ':' part with %c

```
scanf("%1d%1d%c%1d%1d%c%1d%1d", &h1, &h2, &trash, &m1, &m2, &trash, &s1, &s2);
```

But, I also vote to not use scanf and use more robust input parsers (depending on the context you are using it in)

Comment: -1: You don't need trash variables. Add a `*` to the format string, like `%*c` to discard it.